# CGContext rotation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, core-graphics

I have a 100x100 pixel image that I want to draw at various angles rotated around the center of the image. The following code works, but rotates around the original origo of the coordinate system (upper left hand corner) and not the translated location. Thus the image is not rotated around itself but around the upper left corner of the screen.

The following code was run in a custom view in a blank application with nothing else but this.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -50, -50);
  CGContextRotateCTM (context, 0.3);
  CGContextTranslateCTM(context,768/2,1024/2);
  [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
}
```

I tried doing the same using CGAffineTransform, but got the same results.

Comment: Don't hard-code the screen dimensions. As Mac developers found out 22 years ago, and iPhone developers found out anew last week, the dimensions of the screen do not stay constant forever. Do yourself a big favor and ask the screen how big it is. Be ready for the day the iPad's pixel dimensions change.

Comment: I think all you need to do is translate before you rotate.  The second translate, moving to the center of the screen, will not work as intended because it will be in rotated coordinates.

Comment: The screen dimensions are only hardcoded because this was a simplified sample to solve my problem... my actual code makes no such assumptions :-)

Comment: Yes.. translating, rotating and then drawing works, except that the image will be rotated around its upper left corner and not its center.

Comment: Peter, I made some tests in the iPhone simulator and selecting Retina Display vs Normal do not change the screen position of hard coded rects. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Rotation is always about the origin; what you need to do is not to defeat that, but to take advantage of it.

The key thing to remember here is that translation moves the origin. So, if you want to have the image centered at the center of the screen and rotate the image around that center, what you need to do is:

1. Move the origin to the center of the screen.
2. Rotate by the desired amount. (Imagine the extreme ends of the x axis moving as you do this; the left end tilts down, and the right end tilts up.)
3. Move the origin “left” and “down” (both of these being along the new x and y axes) by half the size of the image.

Imagine the motion of the image on the iPad through each of these steps. Or, better yet, take a Post-It note and simulate it by hand:

1. Start out with the note in a corner of the iPad.
2. Move the note so that that corner of the note is in the center of the iPad.
3. Rotate the note around that corner.
4. Move the note “left” (relative to itself) by half its width and “down” (relative to itself) by half its height.

You'll notice that the note ends up rotated and in the center.