# Rotating and Resizing CIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage, core-image

I have two CIImages. I'm trying to apply a CGAffineTransformation to the top image, and then pass it through along with the background image to the CIFilter for blending, but my resulting image seems to show the top image moving around (I just want it rotated on the spot).

I'm also having the same problem when scaling (the position of the top image seems to change).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after lots of digging, turns out my problem was due to the rotation point. This question/answer helped a lot.

[CGContext rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033685/cgcontext-rotation)